# Using an object oriented approach in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, class, mixins

I have two classes, `Class A` and `Class B`.

I've recently noticed that they share a lot of the same code. For example:

```
def viewable_by?(user)
  super || clinic.has_staff_member?(user) || user.system_admin? || self.person == user.person
end
```

I want to minimize the code duplicated between the classes. But in refactoring, I've found that much of it doesn't fit neatly into one class that falls cleanly in the Single Responsibility Principle. I want to put it all into a single module, but the methods will have to do with time formatting, viewing permissions, and a few other things.

As I see it, I have a few choices. (And I bet you can suggest others.) From an object oriented point of view, which approach should I go with and why?

1. Use one single module shared between both of the classes. It may
   not have a specific single responsibility, but it does clean up the
   code significantly, and keeps it all in one place.
2. Make tiny classes and mix in to both classes as modules. They
   will all have a single responsibility, but there will be many of
   them, some of which may only have one method. Seems like a waste.
3. Perhaps use a presenter for things like time formatting, and a
   permissions module shared between both classes. Perhaps "cleaner,"
   but methods are going to be everywhere.
4. Another possibility I haven't yet considered?

**EDIT**

This question had previously mentioned `Clinic::Appointment` and `Clinic::Visit` classes, rather than A and B. Answers may refer to appointments and visits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a neat question because it deals in a great way with the overall strucuture of your project. I understand that `Appointment` and `Visit` are separated things, and an `Visit` don't need to be linked to an `Appointment`.

For authorization methods, like `viewable_by?`, I recommend move all authorizations to other place - you might want to check the [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) structure, that have worked well for many Rails projects, and most likely will work well for any application, even coding an authorization system yourself. So in part, my answer for you is to use `(3)`.

However, since not all code that is shared by the two classes are for authorization purposes, I would try to classify a set of methods, and give an answer for each class of methods you could think of. For method classes that have a similar behavior I would try to encapsulate in a module and include it (so just like `(1)`, but in smaller parts). For example one module `HasVisitors` with methods like `got_on_time?` and `was_conclusive?` (well, maybe not the best examples, but you get it). When your model has a broader scope, like `Authorization`, that is present in most of your classes, then it is time to go to `(3)`.

I suggest you stop and think again if you should have a `Visit` class apart from `Appointment` and it relationship, but not now. After got at home, have fun, take it off from your head, then think again next day.

Comment: I see you edited your question, I hope this still reflects it. I will not be able to modify my answer right now. Hope it fits.

Comment: Yep. I edited my question again to mention your mentioning of Appointment and Visit. No need to edit your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would the design be clearer if you shifted the responsibilities? e.g. user.can_view?(resource)